# Backspace doesn't work in ssh in term-mode inside emacs

Tags: emacs, ssh

I'm running a terminal inside emacs, using term-mode. In that terminal I'm ssh-ing to another host and on that host, the backspace key no longer works. It works fine if I'm ssh-ing from a different terminal emulator outside of emacs.

So just to be clear, I'm not running emacs on the remote host, I'm running a remote shell inside emacs.

Answer (score 1):

So it is your terminal in emacs you need fix, :D

I had a similar issue with a perticular setup where backspace key through ssh act as delete key, seems emacs sometime have problem guessing which one is which in non-GUI setting.

what I did is change `(normal-erase-is-backspace-mode 1)` from `1` to `0`. You could try that, but is sounds like a terminal issue to me.

reference [in emacs manaul about that setting](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/DEL-Does-Not-Delete.html)